# Pymongo Cursor Memory Issue

Tags: python, mongodb, out-of-memory, pymongo

When I got records from MongoDB with Python(pymongo), I think that the cursor of pymongo pull all queried documents at once.

This is serious problem to me because if the document is very large size(include many rows and columns), when do find operation, docker image is killed by OOM.

I tried to set batch size of cursor but still it seems to get queried documents at once and return batch to me iterate.

The dataset is CSV format file with 3 million rows and 50 columns.

When load this file with pandas.read_csv(), Memory Profiler shows that 1.2 GB of RAM used at CSV reader.

But when pull this dataset from MongoDB with pymongo, the profiler shows that 30GB of RAM used at the cursor.

How do I solve this memory issue?

Comment: Any luck / yet?

Comment: @jtlz2 I checked memory usage row by row, I found that it was not cursor memory issue. The problem is mongo query was not return all dataset at once. The cursor was just generator. It didn't contain every dataset. I stored all dataset to one list at my code. So I changed .find() query to .find().skip().limit() and make my code to work batch with multi-threading. And then process speed goes wrong. To solve this, I tuned my whole code with using DASK and dask-mongo that customized by me for my environment. This will be great work to you.